# Problem when trying to play using WINE

Tags: wine, games, playonlinux

Recently I tried to play a game with PlayOnLinux. I managed to install it and it opened but right after the logo of the game (something like an intro, you know) its just a black screen and then it crashes with a message 'Error in main'. I went into the debbug mode and thats what it says:

```
0009:fixme:heap:RtlSetHeapInformation (nil) 1 (nil) 0 stub
0009:fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x33f474,0x00000000), stub!
0009:err:quartz:GetClassMediaFile Media class not found
0009:err:winediag:MIDIMAP_drvOpen No software synthesizer midi port found, Midi sound output probably won't work.
0009:fixme:gstreamer:GST_QueryInterface No interface for {37d84f60-42cb-11ce-8135-00aa004bb851}!
0035:fixme:gstreamer:event_src 0x7b276b08 (61441) stub
0035:fixme:gstreamer:unknown_type Could not find a filter for caps: video/mpeg, systemstream=(boolean)true, mpegversion=(int)1
0034:fixme:gstreamer:watch_bus decodebin0: Your GStreamer installation is missing a plug-in.
0009:fixme:gstreamer:GST_Connect GStreamer could not find any streams
0009:fixme:quartz:MPEGSplitter_QueryInterface No interface for {37d84f60-42cb-11ce-8135-00aa004bb851}!
0009:fixme:quartz:MPEGSplitter_query_accept MPEG-1 system streams not yet supported.
```

Can anyone help me with that? I use Ubuntu 18

Comment: Use Winetricks to install DirectX and .NET it may help, It can be done even without Winetricks